# Javascript and redirect Location: header detection

Tags: javascript, redirect, http-headers

I have an URL of domain1.com, that redirect to an URL of domain2.com with HTTP Location: header method.

Can i, running a javascript page on domain1.com, know the final URL pointing to domain2.com? How?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If domain1.com is redirecting to domain2.com, then by definition don't you have to know the URL pointing to domain2.com? Otherwise, how could you redirect...

Comment: suppose i don't know the pointing url, and i want to extract to the url from domain1.com redirect page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, most browsers will not give you this level of access and anyone visiting domain1.com will get redirected before executing any code on the page.

Even if you could execute the javascript from domain1.com and make an ajax request to domain1.com, the webbrowser will redirect the ajax request to domain2.com under the hood and return success without giving you any notification of the redirect.

Comment: do you know if there is some hack like using flash or similar?

Comment: I do, and no there is not :) this is by design.